# Полиморфизм. Создайте метод который ожидает параметр как объект родительского типа. Внутри этого метода вызовите метод объекта

Tags: java, полиморфизм

У меня есть домашнее задание, но прохожу обучение на английском и не могу до конца понять что конкретно хотят и что нужно сделать. В оригинале задание такое:

> Create class hierarchy: Airplane, Transport, Car, Bus, Train, Bicycle, Tram, Public Transport, Scooter, Motorbike
> Think carefully which class should be parent to another.

Иерархию создал, второе задание с которым возникла проблема

> Create class for testing polymorphism.
>
> 1. Create main method for testing.
> 2. Create a method, which expects as a parameter object of the parent type for created hierarchy. Inside >of this method call the METHOD from the object.
>    Play around passing different class types to method and see what happens.

Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Вам некий пример того, что Вас просят сделать в задании. Изучите как следует этот код.

```
   class Vehicle {
        void make() {
            System.out.println("heavy duty");
        }
   }
   public class Trucks extends Vehicle {
        void make() {
            System.out.println("Transport vehicle for heavy duty");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Vehicle ob1 = new Trucks();
       ob1.make();
   }
```

А вообще, не будьте ленивыми. Нужная информация лежит на поверхности. Всего-то нужно немного напрячься и поискать. Рекомендую Вам почитать про повышающее приведение (или же upcast).

Comment: Спасибо, это то что я искал, не до конца понял суть задания. Сегодня целый день с утра делаю всю домашку, уже кучу инфы перчитал но так и не понял что там конкретно хотели

Comment: Имейте в виду, это не то, что хотят в задании.

Comment: Всё верно. Это не точное решение поставленной задачи, но лишь попытка направить Вас в нужную сторону. Будьте внимательны.

Comment: да, да, понимаю)